# Google Chrome extension dev, json manifest issue

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning to write extensions for Chrome.  In their tutorial on Hello World, I copied their manifest.json file and followed instructions to the letter, but when I go into the extensions panel and try to load an unpacked  extension, I get an error that says the manifest file is missing or unreadable.  I'm not well-versed in json, but I cut and pasted their code, and it still isn't working.  Has anyone else had this problem?  How do I fix it?

Comment: This is exactly as I copied it from google code{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon after the `permissions` array that should not be there:

Change this from:

```
{ 
    "name": "My First Extension", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "description": "The first extension that I made.", 
    "browser_action": { "default_icon": "icon.png" }, 
    "permissions": [ "api.flickr.com/"; ] 
}
```

To:

```
{ 
    "name": "My First Extension", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "description": "The first extension that I made.", 
    "browser_action": { "default_icon": "icon.png" }, 
    "permissions": [ "api.flickr.com/" ] 
}
```

Also, if you do not have an image with the name icon.png in the root folder of your extension then you will either need to create one of remove the reference to the image.

Comment: Thanks!  I do have the icon there.  good eye on the semi!  Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error that says the manifest file is missing or unreadable.  Could this be a folder permissions issue of some kind?

Comment: It might be that the permission you specified is using an invalid match_pattern format: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html - try changing it to `http://api.flickr.com/*`

Comment: @OsgaldorJasonStorm I encourage you to accept the answer as the solution for questions you ask, it helps make sure you questions get answered in the future.